# Как написать программу в Python'e 3.4.1. на языке Си?

Tags: python, c++

Доброго времени суток, начну с того, что препод сказал студентам написать программу на Си в Питоне. Сам препод толком не помнит, как в ней работать! Сказал, чтобы мы нашли библиотеки или модули для этой программы и написали.

Итак, проблема заключается в том, что надо написать не в Visual Studio, как обычно все пишут программы на Си, а в программе IDLE (Python GUI). Если коротко, то в Python'e. Так вот, как интерпретировать Си и Python? Чтобы засунуть, например, простой код (см.ниже):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    puts ("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это как это написать на Си в Питоне. Учитель точно не под накуркой был ?

Comment: Нет) Надо ещё и на Ассемблере написать в Питоне, но это потом. Мне хотя бы на Си разобрать как. Это вообще реально сделать?

Comment: Признаю честно, я ни разу не видел, как компилируют сишное приложение в IDLE.

Comment: а может препод хотел транслятор из C в python???

Answer (score 4):

[@DimanSemm](/users/24022/dimansemm), реализация питона "по умолчанию" написана на си, возможно, имелось в виду написать внешний модуль и подрубить его из питона. Пара ссылок, правда не все для 3.4.1: http://habrahabr.ru/post/44520/ https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm

Answer (score 4):

https://cffi.readthedocs.org

```
>>> from cffi import FFI
>>> ffi = FFI()
>>> ffi.cdef("""
...     int printf(const char *format, ...);   /* Копипаст из man страниц */
... """)
>>> C = ffi.dlopen(None)                     # загрузить пространство имён С целиком
>>> arg = ffi.new("char[]", "world")         # эквивалентно C коду: char arg[] = "world";
>>> C.printf("hi there, %s!\n", arg)         # вызвать printf
hi there, world!
```

Comment: Очень некисло

Answer (score 0):

Классная трава. Я бы решал проблему таким образом:

1. Считать необходимые сишные файлы в строки с заменой include содержимым соответствующих файлов.
2. Через `os` вызвал бы компиляцию строкового ресурса и исполнение.

Хотя, подозреваю, мой ответ такой же ошибочный, как и ваш вопрос.